# Run a batch script automatically when a specific user account is active (via switch user)

Tags: batch-file, fast-user-switching

So sometimes one of the users in the household (with a separate user account on a single PC) doesn't sign out of their account when they are finished and just put the PC to sleep. Now whenever I log in or 'switch' back to my account, I forget to logout other inactive users and this triggers a bug in the Geforce Experience overlay for example which doesn't run when another user is signed in.

For this, I created a batch file to logout other 'disconnected' sessions, it runs fine but I want it to run automatically whenever I login to my account **OR** when I switch back to my account (i.e already logged in). How can I achieve this with Task scheduler or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Task Scheduler** for that.

Create a task to run the Batch file and for the trigger add two triggers:

1. An ***At log on*** one, to handle your initial user logon (after restart):
   [image]
2. An ***On Connection to user session*** one, to handle the switching to your user once you were already logged in before:
   [image]

Together those should cover you that whenever you access your user the Batch script is first gonna run.